# Предзагрузка изображений

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5

Задача : как загружать изображения на стадии старта приложения .
Описание : Написал простое приложение на PyQt5 , которое меняет изображение в главном окне при получении сигнала от пользователя. Сейчас загрузка изображения выполняется после поступления сигнала ,что несколько замедляет работу программы + сигналы могу повторяться . Вот что сейчас имеем :

```
def change_image(path_to_image):
    pixmap = QPixmap(path_to_image) # Загружаем изображение
    label_image.setPixmap(pixmap)   # Меняем изображение
```

Можно ли каким-нибудь образом загрузить все возможные варианты "pixmap" при старте приложения ,чтобы при получении сигнала , мы только вставляли уже предзагруженный заранее "pixmap" ?

Comment: как вы определили, что именно повторная загрузка изображений "замедляет программу"? К примеру, при написании [slideshow для tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c), я не заметил разницы от ручного кэширования загруженных изображений. Убедитесь, что именно QPixmap() является узким местом в вашем коде.

Comment: Опыта программирования нету , поэтому отрабатываю все возможные версии :)

Comment: Прирост скорости появился , но незначительный . Всего 0.007 секунды. Буду исследовать дальше.

Comment: Профайлер вам в помощь

Answer (score 1):

В чем проблема сделать так?:

```
class LazyCacheImages:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cache = {}

    def create(self, path_to_image):
        self.__cache[path_to_image] = QPixmap(path_to_image)

    def __getitem__(self, path_to_image):
        #если инициализация работает
        return self.__cache(path_to_image)
        #если нет, то надо этот код
        try:
            return self.__cache(path_to_image)
        except KeyError:
            self.create(path_to_image)
            return self[path_to_image]


CACHE = LazyCacheImages()

#Инициализация(не обязательно):
for path_to_image in пути_к_картинкам:
    CACHE.create(path_to_image)


def change_image(path_to_image):
    label_image.setPixmap(CACHE[path_to_image])
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо .